# Сортировка избранных меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, избранные-метки

Мне показалось, или избранные метки стали сортироваться по алфавиту?

Раньше вроде как было по убыванию рейтинга, который набрал по меткам. Было гораздо удобней, так как чаще нужны те метки, в которых имеешь больше активности.

Comment: [My favorite tags are alphabetized now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310294/282647)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да-да, не показалось. Раньше было в том же порядке, в котором добавили, а не по рейтингу меток. Да, это было удобней, так как можно было сортировать как душе угодно. Если что-то захотелось поменять, то можно было бы удалить избранные метки и заново добавить в нужном порядке.

Задал об этом [вопрос на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310294/282647) и это оказалось так задумано (by design). Такой же вопрос рассматривался на [мете enSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368024/1548895). Приходится только надеяться, что вернут как раньше, а ещё лучше — добавят [перетаскивание (drag'n'drop) при редактировании избранных меток](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305363/1548895), чтобы можно было бы менять порядок без удаления и добавления заново.

Comment: Сортировка через удаление/добавление тот еще ад.

Comment: @alexolut, хоть как-то лучше чем совсем никак.